# Extending RequestHandlerParams in middleware express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to create a middleware in express that injects an object into the request depending on a scalar, but keeps the original request type and just extends it.

So the code actually looks like:

```js
const injectTeam = (include: Prisma.TeamInclude) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        ...
        req.team = await prisma.findUnique({
            where: { id: req.params.team_uuid }
        })
        ...
    }
};
router.put('/:team_uuid', injectTeam({ members: true }), async (req, res) => {
    ...
})
```

Using TypeScript, I would like that req wouldn't be of `any` type in the middleware, but instead of the same type that the route req type so something like `RequestHandlerParams<{ team_uuid: string }>`.
I need it to be done on the `injectTeam` middleware for any type of `req`. So if I insert another route parameter in the call (so sort of `/:team_uuid/:member_uuid`) the middleware can also "access" the type.

This would be helpful not only for the type, but because I think if I know how to do this, I can also change the return type of the injectTeam middleware so that the next function in it would also contains the modified request object type, even if this require something like:

```js
const injectTeam = (include: Prisma.TeamInclude, nextFunction: ????? & { team: Prisma.TeamDefaultArgs) => {
   return async (req, res, next) => {
      ...
      req.team = ...
      nextFunction(req, res, next);
   }
}
router.put('/:team_uuid', injectTeam({members: true }, async (req, res, next) => {
   // req.team is acessible and correctly typed
   // req.params.team_uuid is also accessible and correctly type
});
```

Is something like this possible in TypeScript or is impossible and I should not loose my time on this idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TypeScript generics to create a middleware that infers the request type based on the route parameters and extends it accordingly. 
Create a type called RequestHandlerParams to extend the req object based on route parameters. The injectTeam middleware takes two arguments: include for Prisma options and nextFunction for the next middleware.  Inside injectTeam, modify req and call nextFunction with the updated req. Define routes using router.put<{ team_uuid: string }> to let TypeScript infer request types with route parameters.

```js
type RequestHandlerParams<T extends Record<string, string>> = (
  req: Request & T,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => void   

const injectTeam = <T extends Record<string, string>>(
  include: Prisma.TeamInclude,
  nextFunction: RequestHandlerParams<{ team: Prisma.TeamDefaultArgs }> // Type for next function
) => {
  return async (req: Request & T, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    // Modify req as needed
    req.team = await prisma.team.findUnique({
      where: { id: req.params.team_uuid },
    })

    // Call the next function with the modified request
    nextFunction(req, res, next)
  }
}

const router = Router()

// Define a route with a single route parameter
router.put<{ team_uuid: string }>(
  '/:team_uuid',
  injectTeam({ members: true }, async (req, res, next) => {
    // req.team is accessible and correctly typed
    // req.params.team_uuid is also accessible and correctly typed
  })
)

// Define a route with multiple route parameters
router.put<{ team_uuid: string; member_uuid: string }>(
  '/:team_uuid/:member_uuid',
  injectTeam({ members: true }, async (req, res, next) => {
    // req.team is accessible and correctly typed
    // req.params.team_uuid and req.params.member_uuid are also accessible and correctly typed
  })
)
```

Comment: on `injectTeam` declaration I have the following type error: `Type '{ team: TeamDefaultArgs<DefaultArgs>; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, string>'.`
What could be the problem ?